# Problems with importing certificats in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode5, certificate

I have a problem regarding importing certificates onto my Mac, for use in Xcode. 
I need to import Distribution certificate from another computer, that I don't have access to.
I got CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest and 2 cer files in folder, from owner of that certificate.
I installed certificate, but I don't have private key to use it in Xcode.

Problem is that I don't know how to configure this CertificateSigningRequest to import private key to my Mac.

Any help would be useful, as I am fairly new to Mac and Xcode.

Do i need to ask for *.p12 file too?

Comment: You need .p12 file also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes main thing is that You need to .p12 file of other mac systems. So you must asking for .p12 file of there CSR and install this .p12 file in to you system that you can used its distribution as well as developer certification in to you system,.